# Illustrator: stuck in Outline view mode

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shortcuts

I go to view and select Preview, does not do anything. I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> and get nothing. I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on the eyeball for my layers and get nothing. It just switched all the sudden and no I cannot get back. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> multiple times should toggle this on/off, otherwise try using the main menu via 'View → Outline'.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get a warning about a preview not rendering? Probably.

Close and reopen the file. If that doesn't work.....

Quit and relaunch Illustrator. If that doesn't work....

Reboot the system.

When a system gets overloaded trying to render a preview in Illustrator, the first thing Illustrator does is switch to outline mode and it won't switch back. If your file is too complex to preview it generally is due to limited system resources (RAM, GPU, scratch disks). And it's not impossible to build a file which is the problem itself but it's rare in my experience. If that's the case and none of the above corrects the issue, you may need to reduce the overall complexity of the file (in outline mode) before the file will preview again.

In my experience a reboot will solve the issue in most cases.